# React Native TextInput the input text is not displayed

Tags: react-native

React Native When I input TextInput, the input text is not displayed. This is an accidental situation. How can I solve this problem?

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.text_input}
  placeholder={'请填写注册时的手机号'}
  underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
  returnKeyType ='done'
  onChangeText={(text)=> {
     this.setState({
       phoneNumber: text
     });
  }}
/>
```

```
text_input: {
  fontSize: 14,
  height: 40,
  color:Colors.FontBlackColor
}
```

[Question screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEvoX.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the value prop.

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text)=> {
     this.setState({
       phoneNumber: text
     });
  }}
  value={this.state.phoneNumber} // Add this prop
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give TextInput the value prop:

```
<TextInput value={"string"} placeholder='textinput' />
```